# Plotly: Display date in specified format in hoverlabel (customdata reading date as string)

Tags: python, formatting, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-python

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({'continent': {127: 'South America',
  128: 'South America'},
 'date': {127: Timestamp('2021-03-01 00:00:00'),
  128: Timestamp('2021-03-26 00:00:00')},
 'total_cases': {127: 20465329.0,
  128: 23470911.0}})

fig = px.bar(df, x='continent', y='total_cases', animation_frame=df.date.astype(str), text='total_cases',
            custom_data=['date'])

fig.update_traces(hovertemplate='%{customdata}<br>%{y}')
for frame in fig.frames:
    frame.data[0].update(hovertemplate='%{customdata}<br>%{y}')
    
fig.show()
```

Running this code gives this hoverlabel output-

[image]

As you can see, the date is displayed as a long string. If I specify the d3 format and change hovertemplate to `'%{customdata|%d %b %Y}<br>%{y}'`, the hoverlabel then looks like this-

[image]

I am not sure how to fix it. If instead of `custom_data`, I use the argument `text` in a similar fashion, it displays the date correctly. But I am already using `text` to display `total_cases` on the bar chart itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, `custom_data` of `plotly.express` and `customdata` of `graph_objects` are not exactly interchangeable. The solution is to remove `custom_data` from the `px` call and rather adding `customdata` to the trace calls. Here is the complete code-

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({'continent': {127: 'South America',
  128: 'South America'},
 'date': {127: Timestamp('2021-03-01 00:00:00'),
  128: Timestamp('2021-03-26 00:00:00')},
 'total_cases': {127: 20465329.0,
  128: 23470911.0}})

fig = px.bar(df, x='continent', y='total_cases', animation_frame=df.date.astype(str), text='total_cases')

fig.update_traces(customdata=df['date'], hovertemplate='%{customdata|%d %b %Y}<br>%{y}')
for frame in fig.frames:
    frame.data[0].update(hovertemplate='%{customdata|%d %b %Y}<br>%{y}')
    
fig.show()
```

[image]

**Edit:**

The solution will work for static dates but if the dates are to be updated in each frame, they have to be in a list and the list can be looped over by the existing loop (`for frame in fig.frames:`)